# Javascript function not found on certain environments having slow connectivity

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, bundle

Following is the exact scenario in my MVC application:

There is one page (cshtml) which is having a grid. Within each row of that grid, we have a button. Clicking on that button is suppose to open a popup (which is a partial view). This partial view contains a Kendo grid, In order to apply common behavior to all Kendo grids in our application, we have created one javascript library (CustomGrid.js) which is bundled inside "~/JavaScript/CustomGrid" bundle.

Bundle rendering code is placed at top of the partial view:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/JavaScript/CustomGrid")
```

Within the partial view, we are creating a Kendo grid with its columns and all. Following javascript is written at bottom of the page in order to apply common behavior to that grid.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Bind plugin 
        var objGrid = $('#historyTrackGridDiv').setupGrid({
            loadDefaultView: false,
            allowPaging: true,
            allowViews: false,
            allowColumnHideShow: false,
            allowSaveAs: false,
            allowRefresh: false,
            pageSize: [10, 25, 50, 100, 200]
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works fine on development environment, as well as few testing environments which are hosted locally. But while accessing the site from specific testing environments this gives following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).setupGrid is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at  (jquerypackage?v=23.0-b68:1),

This function, and bundle is used at many other places in the application, and it works fine there. However, the issue is occurring only in one particular page, and that too while hosted on specific environments.

We are aware that those environments are slow, and it is possible that the bundle may be taking some more time to load and document.ready() would be getting called before the bundle getting loaded.

We tried with window.onload, but as we are already having load() event and we cannot put this code in that event. I am also unable to render this bundle in the parent page, as it conflicts with some other javascript files which are already being used in that page.

Any idea of how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Scripts should not be in partial views. Move them to the main view.

Comment: The problem is that, we have another library in the main view which also operates on grid, and that's a legacy code. If that library is put along side the CustomGrid, then there are the chances of conflicts. I am wondering if that's the case, how come this works in other environments which are having a bit high speed connectivity!

Comment: You would already be getting conflicts. When you do bad practice like putting scripts in partials things are bound to go wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Stephen, I have moved scripts from partial view to parent view, and after that I could see the java scripts getting loaded on all environments before trying to execute them irrespective of the connectivity speed.